# Change context path in a Spring MVC application + Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat9, contextpath

We have a webservice developed as a Spring MVC application, released as `myapp.war`, and deployed in Tomcat to some URL `http://example.com/myapp`.

Now, we think that it would be more nice to change the context path to something like `http://example.com/myapp/api/v1`.

Of course, a simple solution is to change all controllers from `@RequestMapping("/")` to `@RequestMapping("/api/v1")`. IMHO this is a bad solution because the prefix should not be part of the endpoint URLs (according to [OpenAPI specifications](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/)).

So we ask if this is possible without modifying all endpoints and without modifying Tomcat's configuration.

Please notice that this question has nothing to do with Spring Boot!

Thank you.